# Diferença entre echo com brackets e sem brackets

Tags: php

Sabem explicar-me qual é a diferença entre o echo com brackets?

```
<?php echo "OI {$nome}"?>
```

e sem brackets

```
<?php echo "OI ".$nome;?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Por que marcada como duplicada? A resposta para a pergunta inclui 3 itens, a pergunta da qual esta aqui foi citada como duplicada só contém um desses 3 itens.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves Quais dois faltaram que não são atendidos pela explicação na outra resposta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Fiz alguma confusão, olhei novamente a resposta e está perfeita. Falha minha.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves Opa, achei que eu tinha esquecido alguma coisa :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta e exemplo retirados [deste link](https://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/usage-of-brackets/):

1- `echo` com curly brackets permite usar a variável dentro de strings pra separar o valor da variável do texto em volta dela.

```php
$verb = 'add';
echo "Present tense of this verb is $verb";
```

Imagina que você quiser adicionar "ed" ao fim da variável sem ter que redefiní-la:

```
echo "Past tense of this verb is $verbed";
```

Isso gerará um erro, o PHP tentará acessra o valor da variável "verbed".

Mas resolveria se usar o seguinte código:

```
echo "Past tense of this verb is {$verb}ed";
```

2- Se $verb é um array, um elemento pode ser acessado assim:

```
echo "Past tense of this verb is {$verb['past_tense']}";
```

3- Se $verb é um objeto e tem um método chamado `getPastTense()` que retorna uma string, pode ser usado dessa forma:

```
echo "Past tense of this verb is {$verb->getPastTense()}";
```